# Вынести функцию в отдельный поток

Tags: c++

есть программа, как в аргументы функции передать целый класс, и его изменять так, что-бы именения были видны в main()?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

class foo{
public:
  int bar2;

  void bar(){
    bar2 *= 2;
  }
};

void func(foo &f){
  f.bar();
}

int main(){
  foo f;
  f.bar2 = 1234;

  std::thread t(func (f));
  t.join();

  return 0;
}
```

Зачем тут потоки: приводить весь свой проект [я конечто же не буду](https://github.com/Myrkonianin/map), в нем нужно отдельно от цикла while(true) выполнять какие-либо действия.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого достаточно передать ссылку на этот класс вместо самого класса:

```
::std::thread t{&func, ::std::ref(f)};
```

Так как все параметры, переданные в конструктор потока, копируютя, то передавать необходимо обертку для ссылки вместо просто ссылки на объект.

Comment: undefined reference to `pthread_create'

Comment: @GENKY А это не связанная проблема, видимо вы используете что-то посиксное, но не линкуете pthread для поддержки многопоточности